# SQL - Merge rows in the same table

Tags: mysql

It is included in the output of the sql query I wrote in the example.
id = 4, gonderen_id = 3
id = 3, gonderen_id = 4 
Two lines like this. How can I make a single line?

I could not get my head, I tried very hard. Maybe there is a place I can't see or a command I don't know. Can you help me ?

Table user_mesajlar:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | gonderen_id | mesaj                   | date                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  3 |           5 | naberr                  | 2020-06-05 07:38:33.258 |
|  4 |           3 | naber                   | 2020-06-04 21:16:20.141 |
|  3 |           4 | sa                      | 2020-06-04 17:29:32.230 |
|  2 |           3 | napıyorsun              | 2020-06-03 21:21:36.409 |
|  2 |           3 | iyim temp2 sen nasılsın | 2020-06-03 21:21:32.029 |
|  3 |           2 | naber                   | 2020-06-03 21:21:10.948 |
|  4 |           3 | iyi sen ?               | 2020-06-03 21:20:40.080 |
|  3 |           4 | naber                   | 2020-06-03 21:20:17.927 |
|  4 |           3 | as                      | 2020-06-03 21:20:07.481 |
|  3 |           4 | sa                      | 2020-06-03 21:20:02.573 |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+

SELECT id,gonderen_id,MAX(date) AS mdate FROM user_mesajlar WHERE id=3 OR gonderen_id=3 
GROUP BY id,gonderen_id ORDER BY `mdate` DESC;
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+
| id | gonderen_id | mdate                   |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+
|  3 |           5 | 2020-06-05 07:38:33.258 |
|  4 |           3 | 2020-06-04 21:16:20.141 |
|  3 |           4 | 2020-06-04 17:29:32.230 |
|  2 |           3 | 2020-06-03 21:21:36.409 |
|  3 |           2 | 2020-06-03 21:21:10.948 |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+
```

I want query output:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+
| id | gonderen_id | mdate                   |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+
|  3 |           5 | 2020-06-05 07:38:33.258 |
|  4 |           3 | 2020-06-04 21:16:20.141 |   
|  2 |           3 | 2020-06-03 21:21:36.409 |   
+----+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: WHERE id=3 OR gonderen_id=3 GROUP BY id,gonderen_id will rightly produce 3 rows for id = 3 since there are 3 different values for gonderen_id where id = 3 - which do you want to lose?

Comment: 3-4 and 3-2.
When 3 is already in the gonderen_id column, the date column is automatically larger than the id = 3 column. in another query
 , I find 4-3 and 2-3. But 3-5 is out.